# ¿Cómo separar atributos y ordenar por grupos en PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

como puedo separar varios atributos y ordenarlo por grupos com mysql y php?

Tengo un problema. necesito crear un formulario que quede de la siguiente manera

```
COLOR | TALLE

NEGRO | 40 | 42 | 44 |

ROJO  | 40 | 42 | 44 |
```

pero al traerlo desde mysql me queda de la siguiente manera:

```
negro: 44negro| 45negro| 46negro| 47negro| 48rojo| 43rojo| 44rojo| 42rojo| 41
```

Estoy trabajando sobre php

```
<?php 
$tra = mysqli_query(
  $conexion, 
  "SELECT * FROM atributos WHERE id_articulo = '$va' ORDER BY color "
);
while ( $rowsa = mysqli_fetch_array($tra) ) {
  echo $rowsa['color'] ." | " . $rowsa['name_v'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en tu **echo**, imprimes mal los datos, quedaría así:

```js
 echo 'COLOR:'.$rowsa['color'].'<br>NOMBRE'.$rowsa['name_v'].'<br>';
```

Con **"br"** agregas un salto de linea, dime si te sirvió.